# Castle Windsor resolve by class attribute

Tags: castle-windsor, provider

I'm designing a system capable of processing both typed & xml based messages based on a specific (string based) MessageType. Ideally to handle these messages I'd like to use a series of providers such as:

```
[MessageType("CreateWorkOrder")]
public class CreateWorkOrderMessageProcessingProvider: IMessageProcessingProvider
{
    ...
```

and then resolve by name 'CreateWorkOrder' within Windsor. I'm wondering if it's possible to register by name (using MessageType attribute) using a variation of:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<IMessageProcessingProvider>().Where(t => Attribute.IsDefined(t, typeof(MessageTypeAttribute))));
```

or am I required to provide a custom resolver?. If there is a better pattern to implement here I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Configure()` method to do customizations like this on the ComponentModel that Windsor builds.  Here's a sample that looks up the attribute value and assigns it to the name, but there's no error checking in this code (and there's an assumption that the attribute exposes a `Name` property):

```
container.Register(
    Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<IMessageProcessingProvider>()
        .Where(t => Attribute.IsDefined(t, typeof (MessageTypeAttribute)))
        .Configure(c =>
                    {
                        var name =
                            ((MessageTypeAttribute)
                             c.Implementation.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (MessageTypeAttribute), false)[0]).Name;
                        c.Named(name);
                    }));
```